# Android Studio dependencies between modules with native libraries

Tags: android, native, libraries, shared

I have 3 modules, lets say A, B and C.
Each of these modules builds one or more native shared libraries.
Besides that I have an app that is dependent on all these native libraries.

My questions is : 
How do I make module A dependent on B and B dependent on C in such a way that during linking of A the libraries of B are linked and the libraries of C are linked when module B is build?

Answer (score 0):

In the app build.gradle add at the end:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':project-a')
}
```

In A project's build.gradle add at the end:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':project-b')
}
```

In B project add at the end:

```
    dependencies {
        compile project(':project-c')
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Uriel, just one more question: How does it know which libraries it should link? For example module b has multiple libraries. Is that done through jniLibs?

Comment: I can't tell you without looking at your project.

Comment: Which files do you need?

Comment: I can make it more specific: My B module uses 2 libraries of my C module.
My C module is OpenCV and my B module needs libopencv_core.a and libopencv_imgproc.a of OpenCV(module C). I have target_link_libraries for these 2 libraries in my CMake file of module B. But I get "cannot find -lopencv_core" and "ld: error: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc" ?

Comment: Please open another question, in order for another person can help you with that. let's close this one. If my answer is correct click on the V mark.